# deleting lines from text files which are in another file

Tags: sed, awk

This is the continuation of my previous question.
[deleting lines from text files based on the last character which are in another file using awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552256/deleting-lines-from-text-files-based-on-the-last-character-which-are-in-another)

I am trying to get the following output using my previous example? I am new to awk.Please give suggestions.

```
 csh    1      A   1      27.704   6.347   
 csh    2      A   1      28.832   5.553
 csh    3      A   1      28.324   4.589
 csh    6      A   1      28.378   4.899
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking some code from previous answers, you can use this code:

```
while read word; do
    if [[ $word =~ ^(....)(.)$ ]]; then
        filename="yy/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
        letter=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        [[ -f $filename ]] && sed -i.bak -n "/^ *csh.*$letter/p" $filename
    fi
done < xx.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to delete other lines start with "csh" (in this eg: delete other lines start with "csh" except "A")in the original file instead of printing. How can I change your code?

Comment: Looks like you have some whitespaces before csh. Just edited my answer, please try it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to carry forward any information from the previous question that provides specifications for this one.

This may work for you:

```
awk '$3 == "A"' inputfile
```

You can replace "inputfile" with a glob, perhaps `*`, in order to process multiple files as if they were `cat`ed together.

Without having a clearer indication of how you want the multiple files processed, that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^ *chs.*A/!d' file
```

Comment: This code is not working. Your code in my previous question was working correctly. Thanks.

Comment: If what you want is the reverse from the previous question, then: `sed 's|^ *\(.*\)\(.\)$|sed -i.bak "/^ *csh.*\2/!d" yy/\1.txt|' xx.txt | sh` should fit the bill. N.B. the `!` negates the condition.